# Custom version control

Tags: filesystems

I develop an [open source power systems software](https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal) and I would like to include a simple collaborative mode so that more than one person could work on building a power system model.

So far I have a table-based file format which is composed of many csv files bundled into a .zip file.

My thinking is that when a synchronisation event is triggered the following should happen:

- Import the remote file into a model
- compare the imported model with the current model

  - Omit the equal fields
  - Omit the additions from the current model to the remote
  - Flag the conflicts
  - Flag the additions in the remote model that are not present in the current model.
- Ask the user about what to do with the conflicts (overwrite theirs, overwrite mine, omit for now)

**I would like to know about other approaches about how to do the comparison part and corrections and suggestions to what I have came up with.**

thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency#Conflict_resolution